# PDO SQL QUERY - Fill an array with results PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, pdo, 2d

after my sql query, using PDO and fetch() function, i'd like to fill up a 2D array, that i can then display or export in my website.

I am having a weird issue in the process: the first two rows fill up fine in their own sub-array, but the third one doesn't and continues filling up the second sub-array.

I'd like to achieve this:

```
$tableau_pour_lexport= array (
 0 => "filename",
 1 => array (colomn name1 .. colomn name n )
 2=> array (value 1... value n)
 3 => array (value 1 .. value n)
 .... );
```

But i get something like this :

```
$tableau_pour_lexport= array (
     0 => "filename",
     1 => array (colomn name1 .. colomn name n )
     2=> array (value 1... value n)
     3 => array (value 1 .. value n, value 1....value n, value 1... value n)
     );
```

Here's my code :

```
<?php

$sql_query="SELECT id_dossier, type_sortie, date_incident, no_train, commentaire, conclusion_cause, retard_min, etat, no_rame1 FROM sortie_prevue
UNION 
SELECT id_dossier, type_sortie, date_incident, no_train, commentaire, etat, conclusion_cause, retard_min, no_rame1 FROM sortie_non_prevue
ORDER BY date_incident LIMIT 3";

$reponse = $bdd->query("$sql_query");
```

**#file name line**

```
$tableau_pour_lexport[0]="titre du fichier";
```

**#column name line**

```
$premiere_ligne= $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($premiere_ligne as $cle=>$element1 )
{
$colonnes[]=$cle;
}
$tableau_pour_lexport[1]=$colonnes;
```

**#value while supposed to fill up the rest**

```
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM))
    { 
        foreach ($donnees as $valeur )
        {
            $ligne[]=$valeur;
        }

        $tableau_pour_lexport[]=$ligne;
    }   

    print_r($tableau_pour_lexport);

    $reponse->closeCursor(); // Termine le traitement de la requête
    ?>
```

Any help would be welcome !
Any advice if there is a smarter way to deal my sql data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok sorry i was stupid.

i forgot to unset the sub array $ligne, problem solved by adding it !

```
unset($ligne);
```